# distribution of angles between neighbouring vectors on the circle

Tags: probability-distributions, circles

Suppose you have $n$ random normalized vectors in the plane (i.e. all lie on the circle of radius 1).

What is the distribution of the angles (depending on $n$) between neighboring vectors?

Can we at least compute the mean of this distribution? What about its variance?

Comment: I guess the right direction would be: points on circle can be described by angle $\theta$. So you have sample $\{ \theta_{i} \}_{i=1}^n$ from Uniform[$0, 2\pi$]. The question is to compute distribution of difference between 2 consequtive order statistics: $\theta_{(i)} - \theta_{(i-1)}$. (Where $\theta_{(i)}$ - ith order statistics). Moreover, it's known, that $p_{X_{(k)}, X_{(j)}}(x, y) = \frac{n \cdot (n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!} \cdot p_{X_{(k)}}(x) \cdot p_{X_{(j)}}(y) \cdot F_{X_{(k)}}(x)^{k-1} \cdot [F_{X_{(j)}}(y) - F_{X_{(k)}}(x)]^{j-k-1} \cdot F_{X_{j}}(y)^{n-j}, \ 1 \le k < j \le n$